# DB job to generate/email Oracle report output

Tags: oracle, email, pdf, report, environment-variables

The task is to have an Oracle report generated daily, automatically, and e-mailed to a user.

So I've sort of got this working (it works if I hardcode one of the reports server names below).

I created a job on the database that will generate the report. I'm able to get the report to email as a PDF to the destination with this command:

```
UTL_HTTP.REQUEST('http://server/reports/rwservlet?server=specific_report_server &report='||p_report_name||'&userid='||p_connstring||'&destype=mail'||p_parameters||'&desname='||p_to_recipientlist||' &cc='||p_cc_recipientlist||'&bcc='||p_bcc_recipientlist||'&subject=%22' || REPLACE(p_subject,' ','%20') || '%22&paramform=no&DESformat=pdf&ENVID='||p_envid);
```

That works great...

The problem however is that my organization has two report servers that are load balanced. Our server team could take down one of the servers without really any warning, so I can't just hardcode the report server name (the ?server= parameter above) with one of the report server names because it will work for a while, then when that server goes down, it will stop working.

My server team asked me to look for a way to pull the server from the formsweb.cfg file or from default.env value within the job (there are parameters in there that hold the server name). The idea there is that the `"http://server"` piece will direct the report to be run on the appropriate server, and the first part of the job could get the reports server name from the config file that the report is run on. I'm not sure if this is possible from the database level, or how to do this. Any ideas?

Is there a better way that this can be done, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

If there are two load-balanced servers, that strongly implies that the network folks must have configured some sort of virtual IP (VIP) for the service.  You (and everyone else) should be using that VIP rather than a specific server name.

For example, if you have two servers `reportA.yourdomain.com` and `reportB.yourdomain.com`, you would almost certainly create a VIP for `reports.yourdomain.com` that load balances between the two servers (and knows whether one of the servers is down or whether a new `reportC` server has been added).  This VIP would either do the load balancing itself or would point to an actual physical load balancer that distributes the traffic.  All applications would reference the `reports.yourdomain.com` VIP rather than any hard-coded server names.

Comment: This was something I discussed with the server team when I first posed the question to them (as that was how another organization I worked at had done things). They were able to help me with the `"http://server"` portion of the link above supplying the VIP name to use for that piece... however, the first parameter in the the URL is to specify the report server process name (ex. "?server=rep_batch_somereportserver") and that's where I'm hung up. I had thought that there was something they could do on their end too for this similar to what you suggested for the domain portion of the URL.

Comment: @UnsureHowToDoThis - It seems insane to design a service that requires you to hit a VIP and then pass in a specific server name as a parameter.  That defeats the whole purpose of load balancing.  I'm also hard-pressed to believe that when a server goes down someone first has to go around and update the config files on every server and the "default env" (no idea what that refers to) and wait for any cached data to get purged before shutting the server down only to go reverse those modifications when the server comes back up.

Comment: I completely agree with you re: the server instance name. I'll bounce this one back to my server team and see if they can come up with a better solution. I kind of figure I'm trying to solve a problem that they should be finding a solution for. Anyways, thanks for the quick help!